# VBA macro stuck in loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have coded a (what I thought was simple) macro to repeat the same actions across 44 sheets of my workbook (while excluding the first 5).

Here is the code:

```
Sub LoopThroughSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range


For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Group Key" And ws.Name <> "AUX Key" And ws.Name <> "Start" And ws.Name <> "SSummary" And ws.Name <> "TSummary" Then
           'code omitted, but it essentially is adding a date column and a numbered row column in each worksheet/basic formatting     
    End If

Next ws

End Sub
```

How would I add a snippet of code that ends the loop once the last sheet (named "Tech") has been formatted?

Comment: Because you are looping through the worksheet collection (bypassing the named sheets), your loop will finish once all sheets have been processed. The loop will then exit naturally. In other words, the loop you have will do what you want - unless you have some other problem that you have not described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd just need to add:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Group Key" And ws.Name <> "AUX Key" And ws.Name <> "Start" And ws.Name <> "SSummary" And ws.Name <> "TSummary" Then
           'code omitted, but it essentially is adding a date column and a numbered row column in each worksheet/basic formatting     
    End If
    If ws.Name = "Tech" Then Exit For '' THIS LINE
Next ws
```

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to add the format so that the code looked like it does now!  I'll try it out and let you know.  Thank you!

Comment: @JessicaE. A big caveat is that "Tech" better be the last sheet or you will exit the loop early. If you really want that to exit on whatever the last sheet is, I suggest doing instead `If ws.index = thisworkbook.worksheets.count then exit for`. (I'm on mobile but am almost positive that would do it, I'm pretty sure the sheet indices start at 1 and not 0)